# Asp Net Mvc: Can JSON data be returned from Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, return-value, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to do something like this;
- I'll send a Post request to an action(partial view or something else, i don't know) method with javascript.
- Before this action will show me a partial view.
- Partial View will also have a form and the user will enter data.
- Finally, I will send this data back as the JSON data of my javascript post request.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetInformation()
    {
        // The ShowForm method returns Partial View, I know.
        // But how do I get and return the data entered in PartialView?
        var data = ShowForm();

        return Json(data);
    }

    public PartialViewResult ShowForm()
    {
        .....
        return new PartialViewResult(); 
    }
```

As above I want a method of returning JSON data. However, I need to add the PartialView image to the Html page with C #. Then I have to take the data from the form and return it as json.

Can something like this be done? I know my samples can be ridiculous. Because I had no idea.

Comment: In ShowForm: TempData["data"] = data;
In GetInformation: var data = TempData["data"] ;

Comment: The way i would do that would be is i will use a [Bootstrap Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) and then inject the partial view in the `body` section(*where it will only be used as a structure*) of the modal and validate it on the button click of the modal. By this approach, your data will still be in a single controller's context and you don't need to call the partial view from `server-side`(*controller side*).